# Jquery -Combining string & Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and I cant seem to get the following code working..

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
  $status[i] = $('select[name="status'+ i +'"] option:selected').val();
  $odd_a[i] = $("input:text[name='odd_a"+ 1 +"']").val();
  $odd_b[i] = $("input:text[name='odd_b"+ 1 +"']").val();
  $term[i] = $("select[name='term"+ 1 +"'] option:selected").val();
  $dh_place[i] =  $("input:text[name='dh_place"+ 1 +"']").val();
  $dh_total[i] = $("input:text[name='dh_total"+ 1 +"']").val();   
}
```

I have several text boxes "status1, status2, status3 etc. I need to call their name by the for loop. If I replace the "i" with the "1" it works.  I cant seem to call the variable "i" at that position.

Comment: Check the quotes signs.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do this manually? `$('form').serialize()` would seem an easier alternative.

Comment: If `i < 2`, how can you possibly get any other value than 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I can see is the `i` starts with `0` where as your input starts with `1`, so the first loop will not return any elements.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $status[i] = $('select[name="status' + (i + 1) + '"]').val();
    $odd_a[i] = $("input:text[name='odd_a" + (i + 1) + "']").val();
    $odd_b[i] = $("input:text[name='odd_b" + (i + 1) + "']").val();
    $term[i] = $("select[name='term" + (i + 1) + "']").val();
    $dh_place[i] = $("input:text[name='dh_place" + (i + 1) + "']").val();
    $dh_total[i] = $("input:text[name='dh_total" + (i + 1) + "']").val();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
  $status[i] = $('select[name="status'+ i +'"]').val();
```

and You need to start `i` value from `1` like

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 2; i++ ) {
```